# Using readline on a computer that does not have readline installed?

Tags: c, gnu, readline

I am trying to parse inputs for a program I'm writing in c, and I figured the easiest way to do it would be to use GNU Readline. The problem is the machine that my code would be used on may not have readline installed, how would I go about addressing this?

Comment: Ehm, why not as @kaylum said, install it?

Comment: It's for an assignment that has to work independently of what is installed on the computer. Ideally you would make and the program would be ready to run.

Comment: Install readline? Or statically link in the readline library? Or don't use readline and roll your own? But if it is for an assignment then you should check whether you are allowed to use `readline` at all. Maybe the assignment wants you to do it from first principles or has other expectations.

Comment: We're writing a shell so we're allowed to use whatever we want, I'd just rather not go on the assumption that readline is already installed on the machine it's being used on.

Comment: Then your options are clear - statically link or don't use `readline`.

Comment: `readline` is not for parsing but for command line editing functionality. It's probably the right "tool" for a shell. `bash` uses it, but typically statically links a version distributed with the source. -- you could just do the same.

Comment: How would I go about statically linking?

Comment: @m0butt Search the web for that one - "gcc how to statically link a library". If you hit difficulties then post a new question with the exact details of what you tried and what the problem is.

Comment: Link the binary file to your program, then

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gcc in Linux or Mac, you can link statically all the libraries you use in your program just by adding the **-static** flag when you link your program, so that program will work everywhere.